# How to generate .winmd file using VS2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have a project which is windows 8 application that create by using VS C++, javascript and html5.
But when I compile the project (Windows Runtime Component project) using ARM solution platform, a winmd file is not generate. What I success to generate is dll file, pri file, ilk file and pdb file.
Can someone teach me how to generate winmd file?

Answer (score 2):

Check the below image. You need to set the output type as Windows Runtime Component.

[image]

Comment: how to i open the view same as your picture?

Comment: Right click on project name and click properties.

Comment: yes. but I didn't get the view same as you and i cannot find the output type

Comment: Can you please share your screen ? Please make sure you are not opening property of solution.

Comment: the screen shot cannot be attach. But I'm sure it is open project property page not solution properties page

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake. I was showing you about C# WinRT component. I followed [this](http://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/under-the-hood-part-1-c-winrt-component-dll-c-net-application/), I didn't need to create WinMD file. It creates automatically.

Comment: You'll find DLL and WinMD both at location `WindowsRuntimeComponent1\Debug\WindowsRuntimeComponent1` (Please note my solution mode is Debug, it's relese then it will be in release folder)

Comment: It is create automatically but I don't know why my project cannot create it when compile using ARM solution platform.

Comment: I am able to generate even in ARM solution.

Comment: I'm still cannot generate the winmd file.